# Flutter: How to enlarge an Image when scrolling to the top of a page in an app?

Tags: flutter

I have a page with an Image on the top and some other widget underneath it. The entire page is scrollable. 
Does anyone know how to enlarge the image when scrolling to the top to create an effect similar to the one in Apple Music?

Here you find an example of what I'm trying to create:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiYLZ.gif

Answer (score 0):

try to use Sliver

```
final bannerHigh = 150.0;
```

```
return Scaffold(

      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            backgroundColor: Color(0xFF0084C9),
            leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.blur_on,
                color: Colors.white70,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
              },
            ),
            expandedHeight: bannerHigh,
            floating: true,
            pinned: true,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              title: Text("Your title",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
              background: Image.network(
                'image url',
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
              <Widget>[

              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: That is what I was about to recommend, the gif looks like it is trying to do some Sliver but sort of reverse, might not be native behavior but with twicking you might be able to achieve it. You will probably have to use SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate to make a custom SliverHeader.